# RealmCollectionType throwing a compile error 'use of undeclared type' after Swift 3 upgrade

Tags: swift3, realm

I just upgrade my iOS project to Swift 3 and Realm 2.0.2 and RealmCollectionType is throwing a compiler error: use of undeclared type.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems RealmCollectionType has been deprecated by the Realm team and one should instead use RealmCollection.